# Stream of all finite prefixes of a stream

Tags: coq, coinductive-type

If I want to construct of list of all (obviously finite) prefixes of a list, I can define this function:

```
Fixpoint list_prefixes {A : Type} (l : list A) : list (list A) :=
  match l with
  | [] => [[]]
  | a :: l' => [] :: map (cons a) (list_prefixes l')
  end.
```

I tried to do the same for streams, and the most natural way for me is:

```
CoFixpoint stream_prefixes {A : Type} (s : Stream A) : Stream (list A) :=
  match s with
  | Streams.Cons a s' => Streams.Cons [] (Streams.map (cons a) (stream_prefixes s'))
  end.
```

Which naturally fails, since I'm applying stream `s'` to a function which is not a constructor (`Streams.map`).

How can I construct a stream of all finite prefixes?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about algorithmic efficiency, the simplest way to do this is to thread an accumulator in your cofixpoint:

```ml
Require Import List Streams.

CoFixpoint stream_prefixes_rec {A : Type} (s : Stream A) (accu : list A) : Stream (list A) :=
match s with
| Cons a s' => Cons (List.rev accu) (stream_prefixes_rec s' (cons a accu))
end.

Definition stream_prefixes {A} s := @stream_prefixes_rec A s nil.
```

You have to reverse the accumulator at every step, which leads to a quadratic blowup, but if you only care about proofs then this should not matter.

Comment: So what would a more efficient solution do? I can think of the solution that spews a stream `take 0 s, take 1 s, take 2 s, ...` where `take n s` takes the first `n` elements of a stream `s`. But is that really more efficient? We're still taking `n` steps to construct the `n`-th list.

Comment: I think this solution is the best you can do, algorithmically. The resulting data will be quadratic in size, anyway, and you can't possibly get any sharing since prefixes of cons-lists don't share spines. (other approaches like using a difference list amount to doing the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

A more involved solution that I found:

```
CoFixpoint all_nats_helper (n : nat) : Stream nat := Streams.Cons n (all_nats_helper (S n)).

Definition all_nats : Stream nat := all_nats_helper 0.

Fixpoint Str_take {A : Type} (n : nat) (s : Stream A) : list A :=
  match n with
  | 0 => []
  | S n' => let (a, s') := s in a :: Str_take n' s'
  end. 

Definition stream_prefixes {A : Type} (s : Stream A) := Streams.map (fun n => Str_take n s) all_nats.
```